# Почему телеграм бот переодически падает?

Tags: python, python-3.x, heroku, telebot

Я написал телеграм бота используя `pyTelegramBotAPI`(версия 3.7.3) и `Python3` без webhooks Для написания бота я использовал `bot.infinity_polling(True)`, а не `bot.polling(none_stop=True)`. Я загрузил его без ошибок бесплатно на Heroku ([через Github](https://github.com/Veter-ok/ReminderBot)). Но проблема в том, что бот переодически падает (переставая отвечать на сообщения). Мой бот засыпает на 10 минут в начале его запуска (так и было задумано) с помощью `time.sleep(600)`. И я подумал, что он перестаёт отвечать на сообщения из-за этого, но за проверку сообщений отвечает другой поток, соответственно два этих потока не должны друг на друга влиять. Так же когда я запускаю бота в телеграме (`/start`) он отправляет `Бот запущен`, но после того как он перестаёт отвечать на сообщения, я пытаюсь его перезапустить отправляя `/start`, но он не отвечает. Я начал гуглить проблему, но ответы везде разные.

Comment: начните с малого - отладки принтами. Самое надежное. Расставьте в ключевых местах вывод в лог/консоль и запустите своего бота. Когда он в очередной раз "зависнет/упадет", открывайте лог и смотрите, где была последняя запись. Возможно, Вы сразу поймете, в чем речь, возможно, нужно будет добавить ещё пару строк вывода в лог, для прицельной локализации. Также неплохо выводить значения переменных и временную метку

Comment: Огромное спасибо за совет! Я забыл сказать, что бот находиться в группе. Он не отвечал на сообщения, потому что `privacy mode` был `ENABLED`. Надо было `BotFather` в настроить (на `Disable`)

Comment: Еще так же рекомендую ознакомиться с условиями использования Heroku. В бесплатной версии бот будет отключаться через какое-то время и поднять его можно будет, открыв сайт приложения. Советую использовать веб хуки